# Javascript/Jquery continuously check

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible in JavaScript / Jquery that you continuously check with an If query and if it is possible how it works. For me, it currently only checks for button click but I want it to be checked and not only when loading the website

Comment: Put your `if` check in an infinite loop.

Comment: So you want to listen for an event on a button that's right ? Can you please explain more precisely your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval():

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Your code
}, 5000); // Trigger every 5000ms / 5seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can accomplish this with [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  if ($('#test').val().trim().toLowerCase() === 'hi') {
    console.log('Hello!');
  } else {
    console.log('Waiting until you type hi in the text field above.');
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
```